# Hash value file different MD5

Tags: python, hash, md5, checksum

I'm curious, why I can't get the same value of hashed file. For example I have a named file `filename1.xlsx`, I do the hash and got the result, then I change some value on the row, and got the result. Now, when I trying change the value to the first value before, it got the different result with the first one.

The syntax I used:

```
certutil -hashfile .\filename1.xlsx MD5
```

Here are the example:

1. Default (result : 87f77b788fcd3d6f46376c02fa4b0bb4)

```
+----------+
| Testing  |
+----------+
| Rudy     |
| Tri      |
| Saputra  |
+----------+
```

2. Changed (result: 98278a1caaff975584d455a8d9261d06)

```
+----------+
| Testing  |
+----------+
| Rudy     |
| x        |
| Saputra  |
+----------+
```

3. Rollback (result: 5324b0df5e694dda197a9ea874f6e0c0)

```
+----------+
| Testing  |
+----------+
| Rudy     |
| Tri      |
| Saputra  |
+----------+
```

The value from Default and Rollback was different, can I know why?

Comment: Just because the files visually look the same doesn't mean they are the same.  There can be metadata you can't see.  Use a hex editor to look at the actual bytes of the files.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response @MarkTolonen, so actually, it has an identical value, but the metadata was different right?